# Processing 1.5 - How to implement a variable magnitude of acceleration?

Tags: processing

I am just starting to learn about processing and I am stuck at 1 question (Exercise 1.8) in http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/. I am trying to implement a variable magnitude of acceleration where the acceleration of the ball should be stronger when it is either closer or further away from the mouse.

I have no idea on how to do that and hope that somebody can guide me along for this exercise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code in the exercise is currently setting the acceleration like this:

```
PVector dir = PVector.sub(mouse,location);
dir.normalize();
dir.mult(0.5);
acceleration = dir;
```

The first line gets a vector from the mover to the mouse. Normalizing it makes it a "unit vector" (i.e. with a length of 1.0) -- this gives you a magnitude-independent direction. The `mult(0.5)` line then scales that direction, giving it a fixed magnitude of 0.5.

The exercise is asking you to give it a variable magnitude, depending on the distance to the mouse. All you need to do is calculate how far the mover is from the mouse, and scale the direction vector based on that (instead of the hard-coded 0.5 value). You'll find using the raw distance will probably be way too much though, so you'll need to multiply it down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
PVector direction = PVector.sub(mouse,location); //Subtracting the mouse location from the object location to find the vector dx,dy
m = direction.mag(); // calculating the magnitude
println(m); // outputting the result of the magnitude
direction.normalize(); //normalize
direction.mult(m*0.1); //scaling with a fixed magnitude
```

Comment: yeah sorry for my identition :/